# Использование дизайна корпорации в своей продаваемой программе

Tags: дизайн, авторские-права

Допустим, у меня есть программа для Windows NT, и авторские права на неё. В ней используются элементы дизайна `Microsoft Fluent Design System` (программа не uwp!). В случае, если я хочу продавать эту программу, должен ли я что-то мелкомягким за использование их дизайна?